# How to read XML response from another site after submission of a html form

Tags: php, jquery, curl

In my website, I am submitting a html form to a payment site (webmasterchecks.com) and the site responses me by XML response. The XML response is displaying on external link (https://api.webmasterchecks.com/payments/add) after normal form submission(by clicking on submit button). I want to read the XML response and update my database. My coding language is PHP.

**HTML form:**

```
<form name="payment_form" action="https://api.webmasterchecks.com/payments/add" method="post">

<input type="text" name="client_id" value="****"></input>
<input type="text" name="akey" value="**********"></input>
<input type="text" name="method_id" value="2"></input>
<input type="text" name="payee" value="ABCD EFGH"></input>
<input type="text" name="amount" value="1.00"></input>
<input type="text" name="postage_id" value="6"></input>
<input type="text" name="reference" value="Payment"></input>
<input type="text" name="street_addr" value="51 ABCD"></input>
<input type="text" name="city" value="XYZ"></input>
<input type="text" name="state" value="NJ"></input>
<input type="text" name="country" value="United States"></input>
<input type="text" name="zip" value="01544"></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

I tried to submit the form using jquery post and get the json data. But The form is not submitting (not getting any error in console as well). Code is given below.

```
$(function(){
      $("form[name=payment_form]").submit(function(){
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(jsonData){
            alert(jsonData);
        }, "json");
        return false;
      });
    });
```

I also tried to use curl, but did not succeed. Its displaying the API key is invalid where as using the above html form, i am getting response. CURL code is given below.

```
   $client_id = "****";
   $api_key = "*****************************";

   $output_url = "https://api.webmasterchecks.com/payments/add";

   $output_transaction  = "client_id=$client_id&";
   $output_transaction .= "akey=$api_key&";
   $output_transaction .= "method_id=2&";
   $output_transaction .= "payee=ABCD EFGH&";
   $output_transaction .= "amount=1.00&";
   $output_transaction .= "postage_id=6&";
   $output_transaction .= "reference=Payment&";
   $output_transaction .= "street_addr=FGHFHGFG&";
   $output_transaction .= "city=JHGJHG&";
   $output_transaction .= "state=NJ&";
   $output_transaction .= "country=United States&";
   $output_transaction .= "zip=54545454";

    ob_start();
    $ch = curl_init ($output_url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $output_transaction);
    curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    $process_result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

How can i update my database using the XML response?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

My api key contains few plus "+" sign on it. Sample format of API key is given below.

q5Un5ObLZs2ovY2COW+LvHzEVdUy0kR3u6dPwh/p+wzlbh80vONBbo+otLpBwPqnvP/VjhglfFos51sLFDpUHi+6GnVbLtR3ATjSz9trGoKLFgrK/ostPUG4t9XV1EdS10JzVZFscIxUu2LVmJN9NVpCgaD9NaA

Comment: it seem to me you set the wrong form:action value, and trying to ajaxsubmit to a remote server(what is not permitted) instead of querying your php curl script

Comment: Is your problem sending the request to API or parsing the XML response from the API?

Comment: @ ricabral: Using normal form submission (By clicking the submit button), how can i parse the XML response from other website? I am trying to do so.

Comment: @ Vprimachenko: The form action is correct.

Comment: @Debashis but it will fail because of `Same origin policy`

Comment: So, how can i fulfil my requirement? Want to parse the XML response from webmasterchecks' website and update my database.

Comment: @Debashis so are you getting valid xml response from your `curl`? if so, parse it with `SimpleXML` and for the `+`es in your api key check out `url_encode()`

Comment: Using the curl method, i think the form data is posting and trying to execute as its displaying "Access Denied, Invalid API Key Provided". I have checked the API key, it's correct, but it has few plus("+") signs on it. Please have look into the sample format on my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will need to do here is send your data through to a local script and then package it up into a curl request to interact with the remote server via its API.

```
<form name="payment_form" action="local_script.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="method_id" value="2"></input>
<input type="text" name="payee" value="ABCD EFGH"></input>
<input type="text" name="amount" value="1.00"></input>
<input type="text" name="postage_id" value="6"></input>
<input type="text" name="reference" value="Payment"></input>
<input type="text" name="street_addr" value="51 ABCD"></input>
<input type="text" name="city" value="XYZ"></input>
<input type="text" name="state" value="NJ"></input>
<input type="text" name="country" value="United States"></input>
<input type="text" name="zip" value="01544"></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

**Note I have removed client_id and api_key from the form as these should never be shown to the public like this**

**local_script.php**

```
$api_url = "https://api.webmasterchecks.com/payments/add";
 $client_id = "****";
   $api_key = "*****************************";

$_POST['client_id'] = $client_id;
$_POST['akey'] = $api_key;

      $post_data = http_build_query($_POST);

    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $ch = curl_init ($api_url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);//return xml
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);//we only need the body
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    $xml->loadXML(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close ($ch);
    //for testing echo xml
    echo $xml->saveXML();
    //you need now to parse the xml before adding info to db
    $name = $xml->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(1)->nodeValue;
    $email = $xml->getElementsByTagName('email')->item(1)->nodeValue;
```

This is how I would do it, as I am versed in DOMDocument for parsing and writing xml,you can either parse using the manual for DOMDocument http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php or use SIMPLEXML http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php either way you need to parse the xml to add the data to your db.

Comment: I am confused with the above code. Using the the HTML form, you are sending all the request to local_script.php file. Then, why you are  collecting the value using the variable "$output_transaction" and sending using curl?  Please note, i was having an error with the API key using curl method. If i use the same API key in my HTML form, the form submits successfully.

Comment: You are right, that was a misstep on my part, as I thought that is what your output transaction had been. I have now used http_build_query to take the $_POST and put it back into curl. I have also added the api key and client id into the post array and through into the data. http_build_query should encode it correctly and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Probably you also can send and fetch data to/from that URL using ajax. 
I have created simple page which displays map and markers data. I have fetched 
the data using ajax. The response to my ajax call was xml. So after 
getting response, I have simply parsed the xml.

E.g.

```
 

    var url="mapData.php";
        var request = getRequestObj();
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            var xmlDoc = request.responseXML;
            // obtain the array of markers and loop through it
            var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");


            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
             //parsing other xml element...
            }
          }
        }
        request.send(null);
```

Hope this would help.